# How to check on multiple conditions in PHP

Tags: php

I want to check the security input of a form. 
People should answer the security question with the words "allow", "Allow" or 'ALLOW'. These 3 answers are all accepted.

I tried code below but it doesn't pass the `if` loop if I type one of these 3 answers. What I am doing wrong?

```
if( ! isset($_POST['security']) || empty($_POST['security']) || $_POST['security'] != 'allow' || $_POST['security'] != 'Allow' || $_POST['security'] != 'ALLOW') {
      $error .= "<p class=\"message-error\">" . $messages['security_invalid'] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: it's easier/faster to lowercase the value posted: `if (strtolower($_POST['security']) !== 'allow'`)

Comment: You don't need to check both `!isset` and `empty`. If it's not set, `empty` is true.

Comment: You need to replace the last two || with &&. "not 'allow' or not 'Allow'" is a tautology. Any string will be different from at least one of them. But imo the strtolower suggestions are more readable than long and/or chains.

Comment: I think just saying the lowercase conversion option does not explain why the code is not working, which is what the OP was asking. Look at the second answer posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if( empty($_POST['security']) or strtolower($_POST['security']) != 'allow') {
    $error .= "yaddayadaa";
}
```

Using `empty()` is good enough for checking if its not set, or empty, or zero, or null. Then, just lowercase the post and check once for not being `allow`.

Comment: `or`? you mean `||`?

Comment: I do mean "or". I never ever use || and && in php these days :D

Comment: @Randall Really? If you write `$var = $a or $b` you'll get the wrong result.

Comment: @TheCodesee idiomatic keywords are much more recommended for me.

Comment: @Barmar Well, I never write `$var = $a or $b` ;) LOL.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde Interesting, how come?

Comment: Guys guys! Its all 'personal preference' ... we could debate this as much as tabs vs spaces!

Comment: @TheCodesee well I can't speak for PHP, but rather for my personal preference and experience. Code is more readable.

Comment: @Randall It's not just stylistic, they have different precedences. `$var = $foo or die('$foo isn't set')` will not work if you use `||` instead.

Comment: @Randall Well, the code works fine. But i still do not understand why i cannot check this way for multiple conditions with `or` or `||`

Comment: @Barmar good point. I guess though in the case of THIS `if` statement ... using either is a preference. I like 'reading' code though, so I use `or` as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, both logical operators have the same precedence relative to comparison operators, so they're equivalent in this context. You just have to be careful about making a general rule about it. See the [operator precedence table](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) and watch out for the operators that are between them.

Comment: @JackMaessen You can replace `or` with `||` in the above example, works the same. The reason your `if` block was having issues, was you had some conditions which would result to `true`, and thus negate the whole `if` block.

Comment: @Randall. Thanks for the explanation. I know understand the issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem basically comes when you try to compare string values. That's because you need to test it separetely like the following:

```
if (!isset($_POST['security']) || empty($_POST['security']) || ($_POST['security'] != 'allow' && $_POST['security'] != 'Allow' && $_POST['security'] != 'ALLOW'))
```

In fact the string value can be one of those strings and, of course, if for example is `allow` then `$_POST['security'] != 'Allow'` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
$security = 'Allow';
var_dump($security != 'allow' || $security != 'Allow');
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

The first comparison `$security != 'allow'` evaluates to true above, which short-circuits the expression.

You could rewrite your expression to something like:

```
$security = 'Allow';
var_dump($security != 'allow' && $security != 'Allow' && $security != 'ALLOW');
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
```

Which is still a little unwieldy.

You'll likely need to check for errors in more than one place eventually.  Splitting out your validation may help clear things up.

```
<?php  
$security = isset($_POST['security']) ? $_POST['security'] : null;
$email    = isset($_POST['email'])    ? $_POST['email']    : null;
$errors   = [];

if(!in_array($security, array('allow', 'Allow', 'ALLOW')))
    $errors['security'] = 'Invalid security answer.';
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
    $errors['email'] = 'Invalid email address.';

$has_errors = (bool) count($errors);

$error = '';
foreach($errors as $error)
    $error .= "<p class=\"message-error\">" . $error . "</p>";
```